# AttributeError: module 'bot' has no attribute 'run_discord_bot'

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots, attributeerror

Using Python 3.10.11. Trying to make a simple discord bot based on [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yLfjMtsV9s), and I did everything exactly as specified, but keep getting this error in my `main.py`

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
module 'bot' has no attribute 'run_discord_bot'
  File "C:\Users\ME\Documents\python stuff\my python\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    bot.run_discord_bot()
AttributeError: module 'bot' has no attribute 'run_discord_bot'
```

Here is my main.py:

```
import bot

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run_discord_bot()
```

this is my bot.py

```
import discord
import responses

# Send messages
async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        response = responses.handle_response(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.channel.send(response)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = 'my token is here, removed for privacy'
    client = discord.Client()

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} is now running!')

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        # Make sure bot doesn't get stuck in an infinite loop
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        # Get data about the user
        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)

        # Debug printing
        print(f"{username} said: '{user_message}' ({channel})")

        # If the user message contains a '?' in front of the text, it becomes a private message
        if user_message[0] == '?':
            user_message = user_message[1:]  # [1:] Removes the '?'
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=True)
        else:
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=False)

    client.run(TOKEN)
```

I need to know how to fix the error specified at the beginning.

I expected the bot to run, there shouldn't be an error because the attribute exists. looked this issue up and nothing solved my issue.

Comment: This is weird. Do you have a library installed called `bot` or another file called `bot.py`?

Comment: yes i have another file called bot.py [see files here](https://imgur.com/a/1xqM7YK)

Comment: @thequeenjasmine, how are you running `main.py`? Try importing the function using `from bot import run_discord_bot`. I wouldn't recommend using VSCode for Python. Use PyCharm. It's better and easier but heavier. Have you posted all the code in your `main.py`?

Comment: Yes, I've posted all the code in main.py in the original post. I am just clicking the run code button, same as the man in the video. It did work as expected before, but now it doesn't, though I have made no changes since the last time it worked. Doing `from bot import run_discord_bot` gives me this error now: `"bot" is not defined [Ln 4, Col 5]`

Answer (score 0):

using pycharm over visual studio code worked.